# Select properties plus selflink in an Azure DocumentDB select query

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using c# to select documents from Azure DocumentDB with the following code:

```
var documents = _connection.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(_collection.DocumentsLink,
    "SELECT {'id':s.Id, 'property1':s.property1} AS customDoc FROM Name1 s").ToList();
```

How can I add the selflink to this 'custom' document I'm selecting?
If I use an asterisk I can access the selflink, but I don't want to select all the properties. Sample query with all properties:

```
"SELECT * FROM Name1"
```

Is there a way to select certain properties and also add the selflink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the self link the same as the other nodes you are selecting. Using your code example, just add in a reference to the s._self and give it a name (I named it _self for consistency but you can call it whatever you want).

```
    var documents = _connection.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(_collection.DocumentsLink,
    "SELECT {'id':s.Id, 'property1':s.property1, '_self' : s._self} AS customDoc FROM Name1 s").ToList();
```